# Как найти директорию установки rpm пакета?

Tags: centos, rpm

Я использую CentOS 7 на сервере от Amason. Я установил `python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm` с [сайта](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) и получил такой вывод в консоле:

```
[root@ip-172-***-***-*** ~]# rpm -ql python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm
пакет python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm не установлен
[root@ip-172-***-***-*** ~]# rpm -i python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm
предупреждение: python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm: Заголовок V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 352c64e5: NOKEY
    пакет python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64 уже установлен
```

Мой вопрос в том, как получить директорию, в которую установился данный пакет, и почему rpm выдает такое двоякое видение файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> пакет python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64.rpm не установлен
> пакет python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64 уже установлен
> ```

это разные имена. посчитайте хотя бы по символам — первое имя на четыре символа длиннее.

но дело даже не в этом. судя по всему, вы думаете, что имя пакета определяется именем файла. на самом деле наоборот — файл именуют так, чтобы его имя содержало в себе имя пакета.

а само имя пакета записано внутри файла, и если вы файл переименуете, содержимое его (в том числе имя пакета) не изменится ни на йоту.

---

команды (например)

```
$ rpm -ql python2-pyicu-1.5-26.el7.x86_64
$ rpm -ql python2-pyicu
```

сообщат вам, что пакет такой установлен.

---

p.s. чтобы посмотреть содержимое файла с пакетом, надо ещё добавить опцию `-p` (`--package`):

```
$ rpm -qpl имя.файла
```

p.p.s. ну и последнее: скачивать и устанавливать пакеты из файлопомоек — плохая идея. пользуйтесь [репозиториями](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) той версии дистрибутива, которая у вас установлена.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages? 
Согласен с вами, лучше ставить с официального. Но в нем не было интересующего меня пакета, и пришлось ставить с того. что было в верхних строках запроса `centos 7 pyicu download`.
Ваш ответ полностью отвечает на мои вопросы, спасибо.

Comment: https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories , а pkgs.org — это просто файлопомойка.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Вопрос полностью закрыт.